# How can I improve this coding (Toast MakeText)

Tags: android

This Coding Shows error , How can i remove?

```
Toast.makeText(Option.this,buffer.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 50);              
Toast.show();
```

Comment: What is error? also you can use `Toast.makeText(Option.this,buffer.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 50).show();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call Toast.show(). Toast (with capital T) is the class but not the Toast object. You need to call show() on a toast object. Toast.makeText() returns the toast object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"My message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 50);
toast.show();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is Work But What can i do add this Syntax:-    Toast.makeText(Option.this,buffer.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 50);              
Toast.show();---   OR    Toast.makeText(Option.this,buffer.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).setGravity(Grav‌​ity.CENTER, 0, 50).show();    I hope u Know that this

Comment: @SumitSaxena You cannot do this. For your fisrt idea you call the `show()` method on the class but not on the object because you didn't created it and for the second idea you cannot call the `show()` method on the primitive type void returned by the method `setGravity()`